# meaning of the word "fuzzy" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It was used in [Crash Course A&P](https://youtu.be/l128tW1H5a8). It is at 1 minute and 47 second. Here is the context.

> It is kind of like this: you don't want to clean out your fridge just by taking out the rotten fruit and **fuzzy** leftovers.

I have checked all the meaning of the word *fuzzy*, but cannot get in which sense the speaker used it. Does he mean that he does not know what those leftovers were?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fuzzy leftovers" refers to the **mold** that grows on food when it rots.
**The mold can look like fur or fuzz**, and therefore it is said to be fuzzy.

Not to be confused with the positive meaning of fuzzy, as in warm and fuzzy.
There fuzzy means like a teddy-bear.

Finally, there is fuzzy logic: logic based on degrees of truth, rather than a binary yes or no.

All three have in common: something that is not clearly distinguishable, as a semantic trait.